# Can I use valgrind to limit heap size to my program?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, valgrind

I'm new to valgrind and I was wondering if I can invoke valgrind in such a way that it causes my mallocs to fail for lack of available memory.

Something like:
$valgrind helloworld --heapsize=10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, valgrind tries to not interfere with the operation of your program. You should be able to use `ulimit -d` to restrict the amount of memory available to your program, though, independent of valgrind.

Comment: Most likely you want to set the soft-limit (bash): `ulimit -S -d 10`